# Maximum module principle to show that is not there a holomorphic function on D

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, maximum-principle

Plase help with this problem, i am sure aplicate de maximun module principle, but i don't know how do it.

Show that there is no holomorphic function on the unit disk such that $|f(z)|\geq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$ for all z in D-unit disk.

thanks so much for your support

Comment: Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$ which is holomorphic on $|z| < 1$ and $|g(z)| \le 1-|z|$. By the maximum modulus principle $\sup_{|z| < r} |g(z)| \le \ldots$

Comment: I have tried to make your comment but I have not reached the contradiction, you could contiunuar just a little more

Comment: What do you get applying the maximum modulus principle to $g(z)$ ?

Comment: $|g(z)|\leq 1-r $ in |z|<r

Comment: Yes $|g(z)| \le 1-r$ on $|z| < r$. Now let $r \to 1$, you'll get a contradiction with $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ being holomorphic ie. $g(z)\ne 0$